# Strange behavoiur in UITableView - one cell displayed differently

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a problem with one UITableView in my App. I set it up as every other table, still one cell always has a white background instead of [UIColor clearColor].
This is how i implemented `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdent = @"NewSessionCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableSubjects dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdent];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdent];
    }

    [cell setAutoresizesSubviews:NO];
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    // set text color and font
    [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0]];

    // set clear background for selected cell
    UIView *backView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    backView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:backView];

    // set highlight text color to dark gray
    float colValue = 0.2;
    [cell.textLabel setHighlightedTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:colValue green:colValue blue:colValue alpha:1]];

    // set title
    [cell.textLabel setText:[(self.subjects)[indexPath.row] caption]];

    return cell;
}
```

This is exactly the same as for every other table in the app, but in this specific table, one cell is always white as seen in the screenshot below.

This happens on my iPhone 4S as well as in the simulator.
I have tried to delete the app from the phone / simulator, restart XCode, clean & rebuild the solution, nothing changed.

[image: screenshot of table with white cell]

Comment: What does the Xcode debugger tell you in that one instance?

Comment: Everything seems normal to me. Right clicking and "Print description..." writes this to the log: `<UITableViewCell: 0x10c5c060; frame = (0 0; 320 44); text = 'Air Law'; hidden = YES; autoresize = W; autoresizesSubviews = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10c30ea0>>`

When expanding the variable in the variables view i get the following:
[screenshot](http://imgur.com/ge4a33V)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how or why this is, but the problem is somehow related to the `setBackgroundColor:` Method. If I remove it altoghther the problem persists, however setting it to any color except `[UIColor clearColor]` does *not* change the background color but the cell is displayed correctly.